# AWS Lambda function cannot access RedShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a Lambda function with a private subnet within the VPC. The Redshift is also within the same VPC.

However, the Lambda function cannot connect to the VPC.

- Lambda and Redshift within the same VPC
- Lambda and Redshift in the same security group

How to triage this problem?

Comment: You would have to provide details of your VPC setup, SGs, Redshift and more. Your question does not give all details to pin-point a possible cause of mis-configuration or mis-use. Do you use redhsift data api? Does lambda have permissions for that? Does it have permissions to even work in VPC? Does your lambda can interact with other services in the VPC, or it does not work with anything?

Comment: Please be more specific what "can not access" means? Do you get a timeout? Can your application connect but then gets an error because permissions are missing? Might very well be that you need [AuthorizeClusterSecurityGroupIngress](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/redshift/authorize-cluster-security-group-ingress.html) permission.

Comment: Please show the logs from CloudWatch. Did you check the permission in policy?